# How to align two inputs side by side inside a Bootsrap row?

Tags: html, forms, input, bootstrap-4, alignment

[image: Input and labels]

The two inputs get misaligned due to the difference in length of the label text. Below is the part of my code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-auto col-md-6 form-group">
         <label for="category">Which of the following best describes you?</label>
         <select class="form-control" id="category" name="category">
             <option>Furniture Designer</option>
             <option>Architect</option>
         </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-auto col-md-6 form-group">
        <label for="training">Education level/type </label>
        <input type="text" name="training" class="form-control" id="training" placeholder="Training">
    </div>

</div>
```

How can I easily fix the misalignment and keeping the form resposive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make the `form-group`'s `d-flex flex-column` and then use `mt-auto` on the form input to force bottom alignment...

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-auto col-md-6 form-group d-flex flex-column">
        <label for="category">Which of the following best describes you?</label>
        <select class="form-control mt-auto" id="category" name="category">
            <option>Furniture Designer</option>
            <option>Architect</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto col-md-6 form-group d-flex flex-column">
        <label for="training">Education level/type </label>
        <input type="text" name="training" class="form-control mt-auto" id="training" placeholder="Training">
    </div>
</div>
```

https://codeply.com/p/S9wKwrKLch

OR, use the `text-truncate` class on the labels to prevent text wrapping:

```
<label for="category" class="text-truncate">
   Which of the following best describes you?
</label>
```

https://codeply.com/p/S9wKwrKLch

Answer (score 0):

try with this way

```
<div class="col-auto d-md-flex flex-md-column col-md-6 form-group">
        <label class="flex-md-fill" for="training">Education level/type </label>
        <input type="text" name="training" class="form-control" id="training" placeholder="Training">
    </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/t41Lnuxh/5/

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior in bootstrap 4 is that the label will appear above the input.  (Certainly with the code you have above).

If you want the label to be next to the input then try this straight from teh bs4 documentation:

```
    <form>
       <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Password</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
             <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword">
          </div>
       </div>
    </form>
```

[Bootstrap 4 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/forms/)

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to handle it with a little piece of code, I hope this one wirks for you :

You can use equal margin-bottoms for both your inputs and if you like to use *bootstrap*, for example you can add **mb-2** class to your inputs.

Or even you can use **mt-auto** to your inputs.